# Fragment list and gridview in Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make a simple application in honeycomb. I used fragment, in the leftside is a list and in the rightside is gridview. If I select an item in the list, in the rightside will be displayed detail's content from item selected in the list and the detail's content is gridview (icon). Can you give me specific explanation or link about my **basic** problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question. Are you asking for simple information on making this system? As I do not see any problem or error that you are having.

If so, [CommonsWare](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fragments/EU4You_6/src/com/commonsware/android/eu4you6) may be able to help.

Comment: no, i mean an example which consists of fragment list and gridview.a list in the leftside and if we select item on the list, detail content will be shown in the rightside (button gridview).the sample that you gave to me is the content is a list and webview..please help me,thanks.

Comment: You should be able to extrapolate what you need from the CommonsWare articles and work them to your requirements. You are unlikely to come across a sample that exactly duplicates your requirements.